# __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given - After adding array to Beautiful Soup script

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to run a Beautiful Soup script which has started failing after adding an array so I am able to scrape email addresses from a page. I am getting the following error:

`__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

```
START RequestId: 83d39448-093c-4d67-95f8-3acdba284c5b Version: $LATEST
__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given: TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/src/webemailscrape.py", line 19, in lambda_handler
    scraper = Scraper(event)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Additions to the main code block were:

```
self.fields = ['url', 'title', 'emails']
```

```
def findEmail(self, soup):
        email_pattern = re.compile("([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)")
        emails = list(set(email_pattern.findall(soup)))
        return emails
```

```
        try:
            emails_array = self.findEmail(str(soup))
        except:
            emails_array = []

        scrape_results['emails'] = ",".join(emails_array)
```

```
import json
import time
import random
import sys,os
import gspread
import logging
import re

from json import load
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from urllib.request import urlopen
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials as sac

log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    scraper = Scraper(event)
    scraper.run()
    return { "Message": "Scrape function ran correctly!" }

class Scraper():
    def __init__(self):
        log.debug("Starting scraper...")
        scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
        credentials = sac.from_json_keyfile_name('src/OutlookDockerEC2-f9d4246486f2.json', scope)

        log.debug("Authorizing gspread...")
        self.gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
        self.spreadsheet = self.gc.open_by_url(os.environ['SHEET_URL'])
        self.worksheet = self.spreadsheet.worksheet(os.environ['TAB_NAME'])

        log.debug("Authorizing succesful!")

        options = _load_default_chrome_options()
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
        # EMAIL ARRAY ADDED TO FIELDS TO WRITE
        self.fields = ['url', 'title', 'emails']
        self.read_url = os.environ['TXT_URL']

    def run(self):
        log.debug("Scraping...")
        urls = self.read_urls()

        row_num = 1
        for each_url in urls:
            results = self.scrape(each_url)
            self.write_spreadsheet(row_num, results)
            row_num += 1
        self.sanitize_spreadsheet()

    def read_urls(self):
        urls = []
        for line in urlopen(self.read_url):
            urls.append(line.strip())
        return urls

    # NEW EMAIL CODE ADDED
    def findEmail(self, soup):
        email_pattern = re.compile("([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)")
        emails = list(set(email_pattern.findall(soup)))
        return emails

    def scrape(self, each_url):
        self.browser.get(each_url.decode("utf-8")) # Convert url from bytes to string
        #_randomwait(0.1, 0.2)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(self.browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
        scrape_results = { field: '' for field in self.fields} # Initializing empty results

        # Check to see if we reached an error page 
        if soup.find("body", {"class": "NotFound"}):
            for f in self.fields:
                scrape_results[f] = "ERROR"
            scrape_results['url'] = each_url
            return scrape_results

        # Scraping Name, Original Price, Reduced Price, URL, Image Link and 
        try:
            scrape_results["url"] = each_url
            scrape_results["title"] = soup.title.string
        except:
            log.debug("Whoops, some field is not present on the page, leaving as empty.")

        # NEW EMAIL CODE ADDED
        try:
            emails_array = self.findEmail(str(soup))
        except:
            emails_array = []

        scrape_results['emails'] = ",".join(emails_array)

        log.debug("Done scraping!")
        return scrape_results

    def write_spreadsheet(self, row_num, results):
        log.debug("Writing to spreadsheet...")
        self.worksheet.resize(row_num)

        results['url'] = results['url'].decode('utf-8') # Convert url from bytes to string
        self.worksheet.append_row(list(map(lambda x: results[x], self.fields)))

    def sanitize_spreadsheet(self):
        """ Update spreadsheet if there are any errors """

def _load_default_chrome_options():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
    options.add_argument('headless')
    options.add_argument('window-size=1200x600') 
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument('--window-size=1280x1696')
    options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=/tmp/user-data')
    options.add_argument('--hide-scrollbars')
    options.add_argument('--enable-logging')
    options.add_argument('--log-level=0')
    options.add_argument('--v=99')
    options.add_argument('--single-process')
    options.add_argument('--data-path=/tmp/data-path')
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    options.add_argument('--homedir=/tmp')
    options.add_argument('--disk-cache-dir=/tmp/cache-dir')
    options.add_argument('user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) \
            AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36')
    options.binary_location = os.getcwd() + "/bin/headless-chromium"

    return options

#def _randomwait(a, b):
#    time.sleep(a + (b-a)*random.random())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scraper = Scraper()
    scraper.run()
```

Comment: `Scraper(event)` is not compatible with `def __init__(self)`

Comment: You will be more likely to get an answer if you reduce this to a [mcve] and post the full error message and stack trace. The code you've posted contains a lot of things that seem to be unrelated and not necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Hi kaya3, I have added the error message and highlighted the code that was added that seems to have broken the script. The main script block below shows how the full script in order to diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that you are trying to run this function from Lambda. So in your lambda_handler() either don't give event as an argument if you are not using it or add event to **init**(self, event) if you plan to use event.

Set your Handler to fileName.lambda_handler

```
import json
import time
import random
import sys,os
import gspread
import logging
import re

from json import load
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from urllib.request import urlopen
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials as sac

log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    scraper = Scraper()
    scraper.run()
    return { "Message": "Scrape function ran correctly!" }

class Scraper():
    def __init__(self):
        log.debug("Starting scraper...")
        scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
        credentials = sac.from_json_keyfile_name('src/OutlookDockerEC2-f9d4246486f2.json', scope)

        log.debug("Authorizing gspread...")
        self.gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
        self.spreadsheet = self.gc.open_by_url(os.environ['SHEET_URL'])
        self.worksheet = self.spreadsheet.worksheet(os.environ['TAB_NAME'])

        log.debug("Authorizing succesful!")

        options = _load_default_chrome_options()
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
        # EMAIL ARRAY ADDED TO FIELDS TO WRITE
        self.fields = ['url', 'title', 'emails']
        self.read_url = os.environ['TXT_URL']

    def run(self):
        log.debug("Scraping...")
        urls = self.read_urls()

        row_num = 1
        for each_url in urls:
            results = self.scrape(each_url)
            self.write_spreadsheet(row_num, results)
            row_num += 1
        self.sanitize_spreadsheet()

    def read_urls(self):
        urls = []
        for line in urlopen(self.read_url):
            urls.append(line.strip())
        return urls

    # NEW EMAIL CODE ADDED
    def findEmail(self, soup):
        email_pattern = re.compile("([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)")
        emails = list(set(email_pattern.findall(soup)))
        return emails

    def scrape(self, each_url):
        self.browser.get(each_url.decode("utf-8")) # Convert url from bytes to string
        #_randomwait(0.1, 0.2)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(self.browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
        scrape_results = { field: '' for field in self.fields} # Initializing empty results

        # Check to see if we reached an error page 
        if soup.find("body", {"class": "NotFound"}):
            for f in self.fields:
                scrape_results[f] = "ERROR"
            scrape_results['url'] = each_url
            return scrape_results

        # Scraping Name, Original Price, Reduced Price, URL, Image Link and 
        try:
            scrape_results["url"] = each_url
            scrape_results["title"] = soup.title.string
        except:
            log.debug("Whoops, some field is not present on the page, leaving as empty.")

        # NEW EMAIL CODE ADDED
        try:
            emails_array = self.findEmail(str(soup))
        except:
            emails_array = []

        scrape_results['emails'] = ",".join(emails_array)

        log.debug("Done scraping!")
        return scrape_results

    def write_spreadsheet(self, row_num, results):
        log.debug("Writing to spreadsheet...")
        self.worksheet.resize(row_num)

        results['url'] = results['url'].decode('utf-8') # Convert url from bytes to string
        self.worksheet.append_row(list(map(lambda x: results[x], self.fields)))

    def sanitize_spreadsheet(self):
        """ Update spreadsheet if there are any errors """

def _load_default_chrome_options():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
    options.add_argument('headless')
    options.add_argument('window-size=1200x600') 
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument('--window-size=1280x1696')
    options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=/tmp/user-data')
    options.add_argument('--hide-scrollbars')
    options.add_argument('--enable-logging')
    options.add_argument('--log-level=0')
    options.add_argument('--v=99')
    options.add_argument('--single-process')
    options.add_argument('--data-path=/tmp/data-path')
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    options.add_argument('--homedir=/tmp')
    options.add_argument('--disk-cache-dir=/tmp/cache-dir')
    options.add_argument('user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) \
            AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36')
    options.binary_location = os.getcwd() + "/bin/headless-chromium"

    return options
```